# LINQ Convert IEnumerable<string> to List<ulong>

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I have the following code:

`var personIds = from player in myPlayers select player.person_id;`

where `personIds` is an `IEnumerable<string>` that I'd like to convert to `List<ulong>`, since `person_id` is convertable via `Convert.ToUInt64()`

Is this easily done in LINQ?

Comment: @MainMa - take a look for yourself. He has asked a number of questions that no one has answered, or that received no helpful answers. Some people ask hard questions on SO - deal with it!

Comment: I do ask hard questions. Also, I often find the solutions on my own, in which case, SO offers no option to answer your own question. Overall, I find SO to be a wonderful resource!

Comment: You can answer your own question, the button is titled "Answer Your Question", at the bottom of the page. You can even mark that question as answer (after a day or so).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than convert your existing `personIds`, I'd do it in one query:

```
var personIds = myPlayers.Select(player => Convert.ToUInt64(player.person_id))
                         .ToList();
```

At least, I'd do that unless you *also* needed the `IEnumerable<string>` for something else, in which case you could use Nick's answer.

I'd *also* see whether you could change the type of `person_id`... if it's always a text representation of a `ulong`, why is it a string in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
var personIds = from player in myPlayers select player.person_id;
List<ulong> result = personIds.Select(id => Convert.ToUInt64(id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var personIds = (from player in myPlayers select Convert.ToUInt64(player.person_id)).ToList();
```